# How to define a directive as an other directive in C?

Tags: c, directive

How can I define a directive as an other directive in C ?

ex : I want to define

```
#define #warning #warn
```

I get an error

```
error #41: expected an identifier
```

for compilers and targets for example, some compilers recognize `#warning` and other recognize `#warn`.

I already have a way to do this but I want to make it generic

```
#if PLATFORMS_TOOLCHAIN == PLATFORMS_ticgt
  #warn "RAM is not initialized at startup, test will possibly fail"
#else
  #warning "RAM is not initialized at startup, test will possibly fail"
#endif
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @dbush depending on compilers and targets, some compilers recongnize #warning and other recongnize #warn for example

Comment: You can add an additional preprocessing stage to your build pipeline, before compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to create your own preprocessor directives.  The `#define` directive allows you to define new source symbols only.

What you're currently doing is the proper way to handle differing directives on different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's not possible, however you can effective generate `#pragma` directives with the `_Pragma keyword`.

```
#define PRAGMA(...) _Pragma(#__VA_ARGS__)
PRAGMA(message "my message")
//as if you wrote: #pragma message "my message"
```

With this in mind, your compiler might have pragmas that allow you to emulate `#warn` or `#error`
(`#pragma GCC warning "message"` or `#pragma GCC error "message"`).

If your compiler doesn't have such pragmas, you can always fail a compilation by expanding to something relatively context-free that's not compilable, e.g., `char ERROR[-1];` (negative array sizes are illegal).

Comment: I'm not sure how universal _Pragma is, either, but nice idea.